# How do I combine two matrix equations into one?

Tags: matrices, numerical-methods, partial-differential-equations, finite-differences

I have a discretely sampled 2D function:

```
S =
     1     2     3     4
     1     2     3     4
     1     2     3     4
```

I want to find finite difference matrices, DX and DY such that:

$\ S_x=DX*S,S_y=DY*S $

where subscript denotes partial derivation with respect to.

Finding DY was easy. Using central differences:

```
DY =
   -1.0000    1.0000         0
   -0.5000         0    0.5000
         0   -1.0000    1.0000
```

Test:

```
>> DY*S

ans =

     0     0     0     0
     0     0     0     0
     0     0     0     0
```

Finding DX seems more difficult. Matrix product is "row x column". Since x is along the row of S; I try to find DX such that $\ S_x=S*DX $ instead:

```
DX =
   -1.0000   -0.5000         0         0
    1.0000         0   -0.5000         0
         0    0.5000         0   -1.0000
         0         0    0.5000    1.0000
```

Test:

```
>> S*DX

ans =

     1     1     1     1
     1     1     1     1
     1     1     1     1
```

Now I have the two matrix equations:
$\ Sx = S*DX, Sy = DY*S $

**How can I combine these two into one matrix equation?**

The thing is that I know Sx and Sy and am trying to solve for S using a least squares approach. I read that the conjugate gradient method does this. If I can cast my two equations into the shape of one matrix equation: $\ \mathbf{A}\mathbf{x}=\mathbf{b} $ I could use the conjugate gradient method to find a least squares solution.

I guess I will have to reshape S into a vector:

> > s=S(:)

```
s =

     1
     1
     1
     2
     2
     2
     3
     3
     3
     4
     4
     4
```

Next I will have to find a 12x12 matrix dy such that:

$\ sx = dx*s $

where sx now is also reshaped as a vector.

Using my example data and solving for dx I find:

```
>> sx/s

ans =

         0         0         0         0         0         0         0         0         0    0.2500         0         0
         0         0         0         0         0         0         0         0         0    0.2500         0         0
         0         0         0         0         0         0         0         0         0    0.2500         0         0
         0         0         0         0         0         0         0         0         0    0.2500         0         0
         0         0         0         0         0         0         0         0         0    0.2500         0         0
         0         0         0         0         0         0         0         0         0    0.2500         0         0
         0         0         0         0         0         0         0         0         0    0.2500         0         0
         0         0         0         0         0         0         0         0         0    0.2500         0         0
         0         0         0         0         0         0         0         0         0    0.2500         0         0
         0         0         0         0         0         0         0         0         0    0.2500         0         0
         0         0         0         0         0         0         0         0         0    0.2500         0         0
         0         0         0         0         0         0         0         0         0    0.2500         0         0
```

**How is this related to DX?** I do not understand how to generate this matrix when s is unknown.
BTW I am using Matlab.

Thanks in advance for any answers!

Comment: Perhaps this would be best addressed in the Computational Science Stack Exchange (scicomp.stackexchange.com).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I'll show you the code for doing this with square matrices, and leave the generalization to rectangular matrices to you. First we'll generate a data matrix `S`:

```
>> n = 4;
>> S=reshape(1:n*n, [n n]);
```

Now define the shift-by-one matrix on *vectors*:

```
>> E = sparse(2:n, 1:n-1, 1, n, n);
```

and the corresponding central difference matrix:

```
>> D = (E' - E) / 2;
```

Now you can define X and Y gradient matrices, which act on matrices (suitably reshaped as vectors) by:

```
>> I = speye(n);                      % identity matrix
>> Dx = kron(I,D);
>> Dy = kron(D,I);
```

and use them in the following way:

```
>> Sx = reshape( Dx * S(:), [n n]);
>> Sy = reshape( Dy * S(:), [n n]);
```

i.e. whenever you want to calculate a gradient, you first reshape the matrix `S` into a vector, apply the appropriate derivative operator, and then reshape the result back into a matrix.

---

Note that I've defined `E`, `D` etc as sparse matrices, for computational efficiency. If you want to see what any of these matrices look like, you can convert them to dense matrices using the function `full`, for example:

```
>> full(D)
ans =
         0    0.5000         0         0
   -0.5000         0    0.5000         0
         0   -0.5000         0    0.5000
         0         0   -0.5000         0
```

Comment: Thanks Chris! The "magic" here seems to be the kronecker product, which is all new to me. Just trying to understand what it does. I read that vec(AXB)=kron(B',A)vec(X). With A=D, X=S and B=I I get: vec(Sx)=kron(I,D)*vec(S). Do not understand how to "explain" Dy though.

Comment: Looking for info on the web; what is the name of this subject? Matrix calculus? I need some "dummy" explanations to understand a bit better what is going on.

Comment: The kronecker product $X\otimes Y$ essentially replaces every element $x_{mn}$ of $X$ with $x_{mn}Y$, i.e. with a copy of $Y$ multiplied by the element that was in that position. This means that if $X$ is $m\times n$ and $Y$ is $m'\times n'$ then $X\times Y$ is $mm'\times nn'$.

Comment: Ok. Thanks! So now I have two linear equations: vec(Sx)=Dx*vec(S) and vec(Sy)=Dy*vec(S). But how can I combine these two into one linear eqaution so that I can send it to the conjugate gradient method (pcg)?

Comment: Look at the sizes of the matrices. Since `Sx(:)` and `Sy(:)` are both $n^2\times 1$ vectors, you can stack them to get a $2n^2\times 1$ vector, which is your target vector. You have a $n^2\times 1$ vector `S(:)` and you want to get a $2n^2\times 1$ vector out of it, so you need to pre-multiply by a $2n^2\times n^2$ matrix. Since `Dx` and `Dy` are both $n^2\times n^2$, you can stack them vertically to get the desired matrix, `A = [Dx;Dy]`, where `A` is $2n^2\times n^2$.

Comment: BTW. How do I extend this to 3D?